# « Grand homme » et « grand monsieur » (grande dame)

Tags: usage, société

Lorsque par le passé, et assez formellement, on catégorisait un personnage en tant que « grand homme », par exemple dans « les grands hommes de la France » on parlait généralement d'hommes politiques, de scientifiques, d'hommes littéraires et de quelques autres dont les accomplissements avaient été jugés être hors du commun; on ne conférait cette "dignité" assez souvent qu'à "titre" posthume. De nos jours et seulement depuis un certain nombre d'années le monde s'est mis à référer à certains personnages de valeur, presque toujours, je crois, des francophones, en tant que « grand monsieur »; il semble aussi que ces personnages soient élus plutôt parmi les contemporains, d'où une première différence en ce qui concerne la présente question, c'est à dire formulée globalement « Comment ce terme relativement nouveau se rapporte-t-il au terme traditionnel? ».

On doit noter que le terme « grand monsieur » peut être attesté déjà au XIXe siècle.

> Grand monsieur. Homme de grande valeur intellectuelle et/ou morale. C'est un grand monsieur. Le voilà qui est en train de passer pour un des grands messieurs littéraires de ce siècle (GONCOURT, Journal, 1887, p.726).

Malgré cela c'est un terme qui est surtout utilisé de nos jours et il n'a pas cessé de gagner en [importance](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grand+monsieur&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrand%20monsieur%3B%2Cc0) dans les décades passées alors que réciproquement l'usage de « grand homme » n'a pas cessé de [décliner](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grand+homme&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrand%20homme%3B%2Cc0).

Les questions sont celles-ci.

1. Les deux termes ne sont pas tout à fait équivalents, quelle serait la différence?
2. Le second terme est-il en voie de remplacer le premier?
3. Pourquoi existe-t-il une préférence pour le second terme?

Comment: Selon moi, une personne de sexe féminin peut être un "grand homme" (= une personne humaine exceptionnelle), mais pas un grand monsieur... même si pour éviter toute ambiguité on préfèrera quoi qu'il en soit le grand monsieur/grande madame...

Comment: @Laurent Une idée qui m'est aussi venue à l'esprit et que j'ai trouvée très intéressante en cela qu'elle  est unificatrice, mais qui pourrait être difficile à mettre en pratique : la forme « homme », comme nous le savons tous, est fortement fixée  sur l' acception « être masculin de l'espèce humaine par opposition à être féminin », d'où quelques problèmes et pas des moindres celui de convaincre la section féminine de la société; néanmoins une amélioration dans le sens que vous présentez  me semble possible, au moyen  du mot que vous avancez  (personne) ou d'un autre, ou d'une invention.

Answer (score 3):

En première réflexion :
Un grand Monsieur conserve la désignation particulière d'un individu en tant qu' individu . Un grand Homme le change de catégorie : au delà de Mr X, on a la une qualité de l'humanité incarnée, certes par cet homme, mais c'est plus universel.
Vu le siècle individualiste qui se joue, et vue la fin des idéaux globalement acceptés, le Monsieur sera sûrement privilégié...

Comment: À mon opinion, c'est plus le H majuscule qui dicte l'incarnation que vous mentionnez. L'OP n'en avait pas mis. Mais +1 quand même à cette contribution pour ce qu'elle sent d' "*humanisme déchiré*". ;-)

Comment: Et vous avez raison en tout cas d'observer que l'on ne peut répondre à cette question hors contexte voire a-priori idéologique.

Comment: Merci de votre percée dans cette question épineuse et intrigante!